# Making a siyum on Avos D'reb Nosson

Tags: halacha, agada-stories-legends

Does one make a siyum on finishing Avos D'reb Nosson?

Comment: I don't believe there are any halachos about when you make a siyum. It was my impression that you make a siyum when you are proud of the work you've done in learning an entire work.

Answer (score 0):

I did this myself - twice. I've asked several rabbis. One can do a Siyum on Mishnah. (I gather that's what MY plans on doing.) It doesn't matter that it's considered part of *Masechtot Ketanot*.

Comment: It's not Mishnah.  You can make a siyum on it, as in the answer to the linked question, but that's not the reason.